# SVN - How to checkout all folders only

Tags: svn, repository, checkout

I would like to checkout the entire repository hierarchy - folders only. I have tried checkout through repository browser but the option I need is not available in "Checkout Depth" which would be "Fully recursive Folders Only".

Comment: I think this is impossible with svn. You can always checkout everything, and then delete files only with command line like: `del /S *`

Comment: Can I somehow get the entire repo-structure as a list of strings or similar? With that I could go through them, find which ones are folders and checkout those one by one with some svn command?